# Running on OpenCV latest and Python 3.10. Throwing a Module Error

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, face-detection

I'm trying to import the module of face_detection in python 3.10. despite having the lib installed still this bugging me.
ModuleNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[1],
line 1 ---->
1 import face_recognition
2 import cv2
3 import numpy as np  Modu

anything that would help. using anaconda3 jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

You can do `!pip list` to check if the library is installed in your current virtual environment.

You can also try to uninstall the library and reinstall it by doing

```
!pip uninstall face-recognition
```

then

```
!pip install face-recognition
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).